# Obtaining coordinates in projected map using Cartopy

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, map-projections, cartopy

I'm trying to obtain the coordinates of the features of a map using Cartopy but I would like to obtain the map projected coordinates instead of the data from the original projection.

For instance:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.epsg(3857))
fig.add_axes(ax)
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_global()
lines = ax.plot((0, 360), (-85.06, 85.06), transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
fig.show()
```

The previous code shows a map with two lines using the map projection but `lines` (a list with `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` instances) is just only one object with the coordinates in the original projection of the data (`lines[0].get_data()` ---> `(array([  0, 360]), array([-85.06,  85.06])))`.

On an interactive plot, a Qt5 backend obtained after `fig.show()`, I can see coordinates in `EPSG:3857` and in `PlateCarree` when the cursor is over the map so I wonder if there is an easy way to get `lines` in `EPSG:3857` coordinates.

**EDIT**: The example above is quite simplified. I've tried to do it simple for better understanding but maybe is better to show the real problem.

I have a grid of data with longitudes in the range [0, 360]. I can modify the arrays in order to have inputs in the range [-180, 180] and I'm using Cartopy/Matplotlib to plot contours. From the contours I'm obtaining a `matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet` with several `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection`. From each `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection` I can obtain the `matplotlib.path.Path`s and I would like to have the coordinates of each Path in `EPSG:3857` instead of in the original `PlateCarree` so I can use `cartopy.mpl.patch.path_to_geos` to convert each Path to a shapely geometry object in the `EPSG:3857` projection without having to extract `vertices` from each Path, convert them from `PlateCarree` to `EPSG:3857` and then create a new Path with the converted coordinates to use `cartopy.mpl.patch.path_to_geos` to obtain geometries in the crs I need.

Comment: Since you specify the coordinates as `(0, 360), (-85.06, 85.06)` this is clearly what is returned by `.get_data()`. The last two lines are not too clear to me. Which interactive plot allows to see both coordinates? (is it the one that is created via the code above? unfortunately I don't have `pyepsg` available to check). Further, in order to get two lines, you can plot two lines, or maybe you want something else, which would then be worth beeing explained in much more than one sentence.

Comment: You are right the question is not very clear. I've added some info to the last paragraph. Of course I can obtain what I want manually but I was wondering if there is a `get_data_projected()` method or something like this where the input coordinates can be obtained in `EPSG:3857` as the interactive plot is able to calculate them on the fly. I've removed the second question as it is less relevant.

Comment: "I can see coordinates in EPSG:3857 AND in PlateCarree when the cursor is over the map": does Cartopy really put up both ? (I don't have it (looks huuuuge) and see neither "cursor" nor "mouse" in the doc.)

Answer (score 4):

The question asks for a coordinate transformation using Cartopy's feature, and maybe something else.
Here I provide the code that performs coordinate transformation and computation check.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

# Test data in geographic lon, lat (degrees)
lons = np.array((0, 360.01))      # any number of longitude
lats = np.array((-85.06, 85.06))  # .. longitude

# define all CRS
crs_longlat = ccrs.PlateCarree() 
crs_3857 = ccrs.epsg(3857)

# Transformation function
def coordXform(orig_crs, target_crs, x, y):
    """
    Converts array of (y,x) from orig_crs -> target_crs
    y, x: numpy array of float values
    orig_crs: source CRS
    target_crs: target CRS
    """

    # original code is one-liner
    # it leaves an open axes that need to plt.close() later
    # return plt.axes( projection = target_crs ).projection.transform_points( orig_crs, x, y )

    # new improved code follows
    xys = plt.axes( projection = target_crs ).projection.transform_points( orig_crs, x, y )
    # print(plt.gca())  # current axes: GeoAxes: _EPSGProjection(3857)
    plt.close()         # Kill GeoAxes
    # print(plt.gca())  # AxesSubplot (new current axes)
    return xys

# Transform geographic (lon-lat) to (x, y) of epsg(3857)
xys = coordXform(crs_longlat, crs_3857, lons, lats)
for ea in xys:
    print("(x, y) meters: " + str(ea[0]) + ', ' + str(ea[1]))

#Output(1)    
#(x, y) meters: 0.0, -20006332.4374
#(x, y) meters: 1113.19490794, 20006332.4374

# Computation check
# Transform (x, y) of epsg(3857) to geographic (lon-lat), degrees
xs = xys[:,0]  # all x's
ys = xys[:,1]  # all y's
lls = coordXform(crs_3857, crs_longlat, xs, ys)
for ea in lls:
    print("(lon, lat) degrees: " + str(ea[0]) + ', ' + str(ea[1]))

#Output(2)
#(lon, lat) degrees: 0.0, -85.06
#(lon, lat) degrees: 0.01, 85.06

# plt.close() # no need now
```

Edit 2

According to the constructive comments, the transformation function above can be written as follows:

```
def coordXform(orig_crs, target_crs, x, y):
    return target_crs.transform_points( orig_crs, x, y )
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I know I can transform coordinates of data before plotting (this is what I did already :-). The question was about if it was possible to do it after the plot once you have the features (collections, linepaths,...). Maybe my question is not very clear but thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: @kikocorreoso At any stage, before or after the plot, function coordXform() can be used for coordinate transformation.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did to solve my issue :-) The question above is just to know if it could be done internally by [tag:matplotlib] or [tag:cartopy]. After digging in the code it seems there isn't an ad-hoc functionality to do so.

Comment: @kikocorreoso In my code, `plt.axes(projection=target_crs).projection` is an extended feature of `matplotlib.pyplot` by cartopy implementation, it has a method called `transform_points()` to handle coordinate transformation. Regular `plt.axes()` is pure `matplotlib.pyplot` which doesn't provide such feature. So that, the coordinate transformation is provided by cartopy. Basemap also provides coordinate transformation, but differently. Without importing `cartopy.crs`, my code would not work. With these hints, how do you answer your question?

Comment: Maybe it is not really useful to create a new axes (`plt.axes`) for every call to the transformation function. At the end one would end up with a lot of unused axes in the plot, right? Apart this seems to be a valid solution to the question, so not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks. That's the reason why I put `plt.close()` at the end of the script. Now I moved it inside the transformation function.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is saying that it is not necessary to use `plt.axes( projection = target_crs ).projection.transform_points( orig_crs, x, y )` just to transform coordinates. You could do so directly using `crs_3857.transform_points(x, y, ccrs_longlat)` without having to create an axes. My original question was if the `GeoAxes` could return directly 'paths' with coordinates of the map instead in its original crs or if the 'paths' returned by a `GeoAxes` had a method to obtain the coordinates in the transformed projection instead of in the original data. It seems not to be the case.

Comment: I don't really see the need to create a wrapper to `cartopy`s  method when it offers no more simplicity or functionality.