# Getting mouseposition in longitude and latitude in cartopy (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling, cartopy

I am trying to get the mouse position's longitude and latitude using cartopy via the standard matplotlib event handling. But when my button_press_event fires, event.x just gives the pixel position in the figure (as usual) and event.xdata some arbitrary numbers I cant really define, but definately nothing between 180°W and 180°E.

So how could I get the longitude/latitude position of the mousecursor in Mercator projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this answers the question:

[Obtaining coordinates in projected map using Cartopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48196797/obtaining-coordinates-in-projected-map-using-cartopy)

Cartopy apparently does use some other coordinate system when using the Mercator projection. When transforming back to the PlateCarree projection, it transforms the "arbitrary numbers" back into lat/lon pairs.